# Has no connection to other host due to unreachable localhost

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

Periodically my laptop can't connect to other hosts in the same network. When it happens it looks like this:

```
ping 192.168.1.202
Pinging 192.168.1.202 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.248: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.248: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.248: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.248: Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.202:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss)
```

where 192.168.1.248 is local ip address for the laptop from which I run ping:

```
ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : lan
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : ...
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.248
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

in the same time laptop has connection to the internet. The same issue from other machines in the network so I guess there is some problem with router (Teltonika RUT240). How to debug issue further?

Comment: It could be an icmp blocking/firewalling issue, or routing confusion with multiple interfaces (ethernet/wifi) among other things.  Using the "arp" command can see the mapping of ip addresses to mac addresses on your directly connected subnets and may be useful.  Also, try a different type of ping program like tcping which may use a different protocol (there is more then 1 way to ping)

Comment: @davidgo 2 notes that I think could be useful: it doesn't happen always. In most cases I would say it works but periodically for couple of minutes it doesn't. So I don't expect there are some firewall/blocking rules in place. And regarding ping - it is not the only ping - I can't ssh to it too so I guess it is routing issue then app protocol. I'll try to arp and tcping, thanks!